# A weird use of the Past Perfect tense

Tags: meaning, past-perfect

I'm reading [an article](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/11/29/magazine/the-serial-swatter.html) in the NYT and it has the next sentence:

> A few **victims had been assigned local detectives** who asked them to send along any relevant information, and the women now shared what they had.

I cannot understand the use of the Past Perfect tense here, as far as I know it is used when one is talking about an action which happened before a particular moment in the past. And with this knowledge I'm making no hand of the meaning of the sentence.

I have two ideas of what it might mean:

- A few victims **were** assigned local detectives
- A few victims had been assigned **by/to** local detectives

Could anyone help me to understand the sentence?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A situation is being described that took place at some point in the past, say, in July.

*Prior* to that situation (i.e. *prior* to July), each woman was assigned (given, if you will) a local detective. In, say, May. Or April. Prior to July.

Who then (the detective) asked her (the woman) to email, phone, or fax anything that might be relevant to the case.

And *now* (i.e. in July) each woman did so (send relevant information to her assigned detective).

And there you have it.

Comment: I would make one amendment - "And now (by July, say) each woman had previously given information to their assigned detective, but that process has come to an end, and in the present they are sharing with each other what they provided in secret / in isolation previously."

Comment: " ...the women now shared what they had." can be ambiguous: it could mean "shared what they had in their possession all along" or "shared what they had provided to their detective in the collection period".  It could be better written to avoid this.

Comment: @Cargill: We work with what they give us, chief. Don't be so pedantic. Do you want me to rewrite it in terza rima? Sheesh.

Comment: Seems odd to decry pedantry on a forum where grammatical and usage quality are the key theme, but there you go.  To be less pedantic perhaps, but more forthright, I think "And now (i.e. in July) each woman did so (send relevant information to her assigned detective)." is not the correct reading of the "past".

Comment: So a simple addition to the original might make it clearer. A few victims had *previously* been assigned local detectives...